# MySQL Select Row Where Column Contains a Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried using 'LIKE' but it runs into problems which i will explain below.

i have a string column that looks like any of these.
"1010, 2020, 3030"
"1010"
""

I want to be able to see if this string contains a single ID. e.g 2020. if it does then return the row. I tried using like but if the id is 20 it will return the row because 2020 contains 20.

Selecting the entire db and then using a delimiter to go through all the strings will take far too much time. Is it possible to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

First, you should not store lists of things in string variables.  SQL has a very nice data structure for lists.  It is called a table.  Each row in such a table would have an id and one value from the list.

That said, sometimes you are stuck with data like this.  In that case, you can use `find_in-set()`:

```
where find_in_set('20', replace(stringcolumn, ', ', ',')) > 0;
```

You can also do the logic with `like`, but MySQL has the convenient built-in function for this.

EDIT:

If you want to do this with `like`:

```
where concat(',', stringcolumn, ',') like '%,20,%'
```

Note that the delimiters "protect" the values, so `20` is not confused with `2020`.

Comment: Right, but `FIND_IN_SET()` is bound to do a table-scan.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . As will `like` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

This is why you don't store multiple values in a single field. Because your bad design, this is the query structure you'll have to use EVERY SINGLE TIME to compensate for it:

```
WHERE
       foo = 2020            // exact match, only value in field
    OR foo LIKE '2020,%'     // value is at start of field
    OR foo LIKE '%,2020,%'   // value is somewhere in the middle of the field
    OR foo LIKE '%,2020'     // value is at the end of the field
```

Or you could have had a properly normalized design, and just done

```
WHERE childtable.foo = 2020
```

and be done with it.